# What is the expected performance gap switching from SQL to TSDB for handling time series?

Tags: sql, performance, time-series

We are in the case of using a SQL database for a single node storage of roughly 1 hour of high frequency metrics (several k inserts a second). We quickly ran into I/O issues which proper buffering would not simply handle, and we are willing to put time into solving the performance issue.

I suggested to switch to a specialised database for handling time series, but my colleague stayed pretty skeptical. His argument is that the gain "out of the box" is not guaranteed as he knows SQL well and already spent time optimizing the storage, and we in comparison do not have any kind of TSDB experience to properly optimize it.

My intuition is that using a TSDB would be much more efficient even with an out of box configuration but I don't have any data to measure this, and internet benchs such as InfluxDB's are nowhere near trustable. We should run our own, except we can't affoard to loose time in a dead end or a mediocre improvement.

What would be, in my use case but very roughly, the performance gap between relational storage and TSDB, when it comes to single node throughput ?

Comment: So you're asking if a TSDB is faster than a SQL database/backend of whatever sort? Do you really want to make a decision based on our answers to that vague question?

Comment: @jarlh If you need more precision about my use case or question, then ask for the relevant details. I'm willing to provide more, but I do not know what may or may not be relevant nor I know exactly all the details of our current use case. I want an overall picture of what I can expect to gain if I'm doing X or Y.

Answer (score 1):

This question may be bordering on a software recommendation.  I just want to point one important thing out:  You have an existing code base so switching to another data store is expensive in terms of development costs and time.  If you have someone experienced with the current technology, you are probably better off with a good-faith effort to make that technology work.

Whether you switch or not depends on the actual requirements of your application.  For instance, if you don't need the data immediately, perhaps writing batches to a file is the most efficient mechanism.

Your infrastructure has ample opportunity for in-place growth -- more memory, more processors, solid-state disk (for example).  These might meet your performance needs with a minimal amount of effort.

If you cannot make the solution work (and 10k inserts per second should be quite feasible), then there are numerous solutions.  Some NOSQL databases relax some of the strict ACID requirements of traditional RDBMSs, providing faster throughout.

Comment: I tried not to step in software recommendation by keeping the talk about technology, no particular names. We need the data to be immediately available. We have studied in-place growth options already. Right now one of the suggestions was to write in /dev/shm and rotate the db file on disk for persistance every now and then, but then we needed to code some logic to keep updating the base while rotating it. Eventually, we will get a working solution but I wanted to know if anyone had expertise about potential gain using a TSDB for TS data.